# Expected amount of linearly dependent random vectors?

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, matrices, random-matrices

Given a random Matrix $A\in \mathbb{F}_2^{n\times n}$ what is the expectation value of the amount of linearly dependent row-vectors of $A$?

EDIT: As said in the comments, I'm looking for the expected number of zero-rows after applying gaussian elimination on the rows of $A$.

I just figured out, that the probability that there is no linearly dependent vector is $$\Pr[n]=\prod_{k=1}^n(1-2^{-k})$$
But i'm not sure if this can help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: by "vectors" do you mean the column vectors of $A$?

Comment: column vectors or row vectors, shouldn't matter anyway

Comment: And what do you mean by "amount"? What is the number of linearly dependent vectors when $A = (v, v, w, w, w)$ for $v$ and $w$ being linearly independent elements of $\mathbb{F}_2^5$? What is the number for $$ B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} ?$$ How about its transpose $B^T$?

Comment: Ok, that matters ;-) what i mean is the number of zero rows after applying gaussian elimination on the rows of $A$. So in the Case of $B$ the number would be 1

Comment: Okay, so you are in fact looking for the expectation value of the nullity of $A$ (equivalently the rank, since rank = n - nullity). By random matrix you mean that all entries are independent Bournoulli with $p = 1/2$, I assume?

Comment: yes, that's it :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been previously answered on Math.SE ; see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324150/expected-rank-of-a-random-binary-matrix